# Unhashable type error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df.shape

(86, 245)
```

However, when I do this:

```
df[0, :]
```

I get the error:

```
*** TypeError: unhashable type
```

How do I fix this? I just want to get the first row

Comment: Can you please show us how you construct `df`? Right now we can only guess what happens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If need first row as `Series` just use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[0, :]
```

But if need `DataFrame` use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) but add `[]` or use [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df.iloc[[0], :]
df.head(1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.iloc[0, :])
A    1
B    4
C    7
D    1
E    5
F    7
Name: 0, dtype: int64

print (df.head(1))
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7

print (df.iloc[[0], :])
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
```

Answer (score 9):

I had `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series` while trying to use `.loc` function over a `ps.Dataframe`.

**My mistake was to use `.loc` as `.loc(...)` when it is supposed to be `.loc[...]`**

Example of the mistake:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)

# typical mistake
print(df.loc(
    df["A"] == 1
))
```

result:

```bash
PS C:\Users\rascoussier\python\stackoverflow\type_error_with_df_loc> C:\Users\rascoussier\Anaconda3\envs\elastic-1\python.exe .\main.py                                 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rascoussier\python\stackoverflow\type_error_with_df_loc\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(df.loc(
  File "C:\Users\rascoussier\Anaconda3\envs\elastic-1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 634, in __call__
    axis = self.obj._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "C:\Users\rascoussier\Anaconda3\envs\elastic-1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 550, in _get_axis_number
    return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

This mistake is not detected by Pylance on VSCode. I don't know why. But below is the correction.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)

# correction
print("Correction works, see below: ")
print(df.loc[
    df["A"] == 1
])
```

result:

```py
PS C:\Users\rascoussier\python\stackoverflow\type_error_with_df_loc> C:\Users\rascoussier\Anaconda3\envs\elastic-1\python.exe .\main.py
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
Correction works, see below:
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
```

Remark: My example is slightly different from the one asked by the question, but since I found this solution while searching, it might help others with the same issue.

Comment: Thank you!! It happens to me all the time, and yet there's always that one morning in which I don't spot it...

Comment: My mistake was to forget ".loc" ("df[series,'a']" instead of "df.loc[series, 'a']")...