# tf-idf in python. I wish to combine the tf-idf values in one csv file

Tags: python

I have calculated tf-idf matrices for 3 different columns in a .csv file and now want to store these values in one single csv file with column names as the column whose tf-idf values it is storing. I am new to python. Please help me with this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import csv

data=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\amgup\Downloads\classification\Model_Dataset.xlsx", usecols=['Category','Title','Description'])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
matrix1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Category'].values.astype(str))
matrix2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Title'].values.astype(str))
matrix3 = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['Description'].values.astype(str))
```

Comment: Please provide us with code so we can help you.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it once

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `np.savetxt` ?

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', (matrix1 , matrix1 2, matrix3), delimiter=',')
```

[EDIT]

try using pandas module to save it to csv.

example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({matrix1, matrix2, matrix3})
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I did but it's throwing this error:
v = format % tuple(row) + newline
TypeError: must be real number, not csr_matrix

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: I edited my answer, try new changes in your code and please tell me if it is working.

Comment: It's still throwing an error:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'csr_matrix'

Comment: Try to find answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796290/unhashable-type-error-in-pandas-dataframe). Link is mentioning unhashable type error in pandas dataframe. It might help you.